# Can't set target framework to 2.0 C++/CLI

Tags: .net, frameworks, c++-cli

Project.vcxproj file contains the following:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jXTa.png]

This is what's written in the project common properties: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3s3v.png]

The compiled executable still requires .net 4.0 
[image: http:// i.stack.imgur.com/zPFTW.png]

How can I set it to .net 2.0? I need to use it as a .dll in my vb.net 2.0 project.

The platform toolset is Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp).

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/780602/compiling-c-clr-dll-in-vs-2012-targeting-net-2-0-introduces-indirect-dependency-on-net-4-0